# Alert and Detect Firewall Activity

Tags: powershell

Is there any way, with PowerShell, to set up a sort of monitoring/alert/capture for firewall activity (i.e. blocks and allows, inbound and outbound)?

Comment: I came up with a bunch of info on APIs to control the firewall, but not really to monitor it.  PowerShell more broadly can use anything that .NET can, and I looked there, too.  The closest option I could think of might be to enable logging and to use the log file to rig something janky up.

Comment: @ChrisN I like that logging idea.  Do you have any links on that?

Comment: With the lack of other input on how to solve this I changed my comment to an answer and added a link to enabling logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a bunch of info on APIs to control the firewall, but not really to monitor it. PowerShell more broadly can use anything that .NET can, and I looked there, too. The closest option I could think of might be to enable logging and to use the log file to rig something janky up.  Here's a link to how logging can be enabled:

http://blink.ucsd.edu/technology/security/firewall/windows7-a.html#4.-Enable-logging-to-view-denie

From there you will use Get-Content on the log file... and depending on what exactly you're trying to do you'll have to parse the text, maybe do some action, and then maybe log that to some other storage (XML or something) for handled events or save the last run time of your script somewhere and compare that to the date in the events in the log.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide here on how to access the Windows Firewall. This is Powershell version of  netsh advfirewall.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831755.aspx

Not sure if this is what you are looking for ?

Comment: I didn't find anything in that article that showed about active monitoring of blocking and allowing ports real-time, inbound and outbound.

Comment: Active Monitoring would require Powershell events

Comment: I presume, active monitoring would require Powershell events / jobs using Register-ObjectEvent or such. Even with those, powershell is serverely handicapped when it comes to long-running jobs.

The netsh and other powershell cmdlets, at best will allow you to modify the firewall rules.

I saw these 2 cmdlets earlier and hence referred you to the link.
netsh advfirewall monitor show mmsa all
Get-NetIPsecMainModeSA

PS: These work in Server 2010/Win8 *only*